Beamer: adjust the height of a picture in one column to the height of another column
I have a columns environment with two columns. The left column contains text. The right column contains a picture. I would like to set the width of the picture to the width of the column and the height of the picture to the height of the column, as determined by the quantity of text in the first column. I know how to set the width of the picture, namely width=\columnwidth. But how can I set the height? I thought that height=\columnheight might work, but it doesn't.
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\column{0.6\textwidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed consequat lobortis felis, in varius urna feugiat a. Nunc tempus quam metus. Vivamus rhoncus ultricies tellus mollis luctus. Etiam vitae tellus sit amet dolor suscipit lobortis eu in magna. Aliquam erat volutpat.
\column{0.37\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


You could use tcolorboxes instead of columns:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\tcbset{
nobeforeafter,
enhanced jigsaw,
frame hidden,
interior hidden,
size=minimal
}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=.6\textwidth,equal height group=foo]
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  \begin{itemize}
  \item test
  \item test
  \end{itemize}
  Sed consequat lobortis felis, in varius urna feugiat a. Nunc tempus quam metus. Vivamus rhoncus ultricies tellus mollis luctus. Etiam vitae tellus sit
\end{tcolorbox}%
\hfill
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=.35\textwidth,use height from group=foo]
\tcbheightfromgroup{\quack}{foo}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\quack]{example-image-duck}
\end{tcolorbox}%


\end{frame}

\end{document}



The code provided works fine, thank you! But there is a complication in my concrete case: The left column contains an unordered list with two items, i.e., \begin{itemize} \item ... \item ... \end{itemize}, not just plain text. And when I replace the dummy text in your code with this itemize environment, the code does not work at all: the picture comes out either too big or too small. Does this behavior have to do with the specifics of tcolorbox?

@Wolfhart Works fine for me

If the left column contains only the itemize environment, then it does not work. If the text in each \item is very short (a couple of words), then the picture is too large; if the text in each \item is long (a couple of sentences), then the picture is too small.

@Wolfhart still works fine: https://i.sstatic.net/oTTaQL2A.png

I figured out what the problem was: After changing the length of the text in the left column, I have to compile the code twice for the size of the picture to adapt to the new height of the column.

@Wolfhart use latexmk to compile your documents. It will automatically figure out how many compilations are necessary.

You could use minipages. First measure the height of the text-minipage and then use this information to scale the image:
\documentclass{beamer}

\newsavebox\quack
\newdimen\quackht 
\newdimen\quackdp 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\sbox\quack{%
  \begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed consequat lobortis felis, in varius urna feugiat a. Nunc tempus quam metus. Vivamus rhoncus ultricies tellus mollis luctus. Etiam vitae tellus sit
  \end{minipage}%
}
\settoheight{\quackht}{\usebox{\quack}}
\settodepth{\quackdp}{\usebox{\quack}}

\usebox{\quack}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.35\linewidth}
\includegraphics[height=\dimexpr\quackht+\quackdp,width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}%


\end{frame}

\end{document}


